# Cannot give myself root my permissions

Tags: bash, terminal

I am trying to give myself root access to all the file in this folder and not have to `sudo` everything I want to run a command.

The file I am concerned with is `pro`

When I enter `ls -l` I get :

```
drwxr-xr-x+  12 Guest  _guest   384 13 Jan 14:56 Guest
drwxrwxrwt    9 root   wheel    288 13 Jan 14:30 Shared
drwxr-xr-x+ 148 Santi  staff   4736  1 Apr 17:13 pro
```

then I enter `chmod 775 pro/`

It doesnt seem to change the permssions. What can I do to fix this or why is the folder restricting permission even though I appear to be root?

Comment: Does it throw an error when you try to chmod it? If not, is this an NTFS partition that is mounted?

Comment: The plus means the permissions are set by ACLs and not traditional Unix permissions.

Comment: @JNevill no it doesnt throw errors.

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks for your input. How do I bypass these?

Comment: @JNevill I am not sure . I recently install a 1 tb sparta drive, but this has always driven crazy before that upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drwxr-xr-x+  ...`

the final **+** means that the file is governed by acl

see

- `apropos acl` : give you the mans to consult
- [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)
- [Access Control Lists on Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ACL)

Comment: Thanks for chiming in @kyodev. Can you please add a link or explain further as I am still unclear of how to proceed